# NLTK, Ngrams and concordance--Multiple words

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am working on some newspaper archives, on some banking related coverage. My problem is that names such as Bank of America Merrill Lynch, Morgan Stanley and JP Morgan are reported differently is different countries: BankAM, BofA, BAML, or MS, JPM, J.P. Morgan, JP. Morgan. I am using a regexp tokenizer for pre-processing. How do I build some kind of an equivalence/look up table? That Citigroup is the same thing (in news reporting) as Citibank, Citi, Citi Group and Citi Bank. Any help will be much appreciated.
@ jksnw: A dictionary maps one word to many. In this case, I need to map many variations to one 'proper noun'. This also means that I need to read {Bank of America Merrill Lynch} as one NNP and on the flip side read {MS} as a NNP --in the proper context--as equivalent to Morgan Stanley.

Comment: Your title doesn't really match your question. Could you change it to make it more descriptive?

Comment: Perhaps a bit more information about what preprocessing is going on. Is it just your regex tokenizer, and what is it meant to do exactly? Also, I agree with @MJeffryes, the title could be better.

Comment: How about a dictionary where the keys are the alternative names and the value is the 'proper' name? I was thinking the dictionary might look like `{"BankAM":"Bank of America Merrill Lynch", "BofA","Bank of America Merrill Lynch", "BAML":"Bank of America Merrill Lynch"}`, then you could check if a name is a key in the dictionary and replace it with the value.

Comment: Was the dictionary idea helpful at all? i.e. Enough to put as an answer?

Comment: @jksnw: Thank for the tip. I implemented your version, but it depends heavily of me populating the dictionary with known keys. Over the weekend, I implemented a brute force sub-routine, which led me to think of a dictionary where: I kind of park two or more instances of NNPs in a temp array (till sequence broken by VB or something else) and then iterate this sequence over a dict. Which begets the next point: while iterating over keys in a dict, can I make the key a list? Thanks much.

Comment: Interesting question about having a list as a key, just tried it `dict = {["one","two"]:"three"}` gives an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. So thats a no.